# What is and where to use function ($value) : SomeClass

Tags: php

I have seen on one presentation code like this:

```
public function ($value) : SomeClass
{
  //...
}
```

or

```
public function ($value) :? SomeClass
{
  //...
}
```

What is this and where to use?

Comment: Are you sure about the 2nd ?

Comment: Welcome to PHP 7.x. Those are return types. `:` denotes the return type of a function, in your case `SomeClass`. `?:` denotes a possible `null` return type besides the usual `SomeClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first code sample is a **[return type](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations) (PHP 7.0+)** which works *similarly* as [OOP Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration):

```
// You will return a SomeClass instance
public function ($value) : SomeClass
```

The second sample is a **[nullable return type](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php) (PHP 7.1+)**:

```
// You will return a SomeClass instance or null
public function ($value) : ?SomeClass
```

Another thing interesting in **PHP7's return types** is the **[object return type](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.new-features.php) (PHP 7.2+)**:

```
// You can return any class instance (SomeClass, MyClass, YourClass ...)
public function ($value) : object
```

---

For example, having a method with *return type* `string` won't let you return an `array`:

```
public function print(string $str) : string
{ return [$str]; }
```

This will return:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Class::print() must be of the type string, array returned

---

See also:

- [Type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)
- [Void functions (PHP 7.1+)](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.void-functions)

Comment: oh, yes, fixed typo